# have an error when creating a table in phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to create a table and this the SQL queries

```
CREATE TABLE person {
    per_id int(10) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    clth_color varchar(256) not null,
    per_photo varchar(256) not null,
    age varchar(10) not null,
    description text not null,
    loaction varchar(256) not null,
    type int(1) not null,
    user_id int(10) not null,
    primary key(per_id),
    foreign key(user_id) references users(user_id) 

};
```

but i get an error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{

```
per_id int(10) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(256) not null,
```

' at line 1

Comment: Did You try to replace {} with () ?

Comment: GREAT , it solved

Answer (score 0):

Try using () instead {}

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    per_id int(10) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    clth_color varchar(256) not null,
    per_photo varchar(256) not null,
    age varchar(10) not null,
    description text not null,
    loaction varchar(256) not null,
    type int(1) not null,
    user_id int(10) not null,
    primary key(per_id),
    foreign key(user_id) references users(user_id) 
);
```

I'm not entirely sure but it might work.